# How get meta data from url (icon and site name)?

Tags: android, url

How get meta data from url (icon and site name) ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is highly subjective, depending on the site, and not all sites are created equal. You seem to be looking for a general answer.

To get the icon, do a curl request to get the page html, then parse it, looking for a link tag rel="shortcut icon":

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/icons/mail/images/favicon5.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

If you can't find one, then try to do a curl request for example.com/favicon.ico as this is the default that most browsers will fall back to automatically. You could then try to pick out the first image in the page.

For the title, you can look for the

```
<title>Example Title</title>
```

tag, or the description meta tag.

All these things will only go so far. You will have mixed results with varying websites. There is no complete solution for this since not all websites are created equal. I would say it's a good starting place, and depending on your application, I would say it might be advantageous to stockpile a list of common domains that map to icons and titles.